# Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: php, html, unix, w3c-validation

I tested my HTML5 [webpage](http://www.znamykadernik.cz) on w3c validator and got [errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.znamykadernik.cz%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

```
"Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>"
```

But as you can see, I have doctype at first place. I found a post here [HTML validation error: Non-space characters found before DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051941/html-validation-error-non-space-characters-found-before-doctype) saying something about BOM files. <s>I am not sure if there can be BOM files in my source code.</s>

<s>Is there any way how to find BOM files recursively for a given directory using unix commands?</s>

Is there any other reason why mentioned error displays to me?

**UPDATE:**

As watcher suggested, according to command

```
grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .
```

from topic [Elegant way to search for UTF-8 files with BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom) there are no BOM source code files in my source code. So this is probably not matter of BOM files and there must be something else causing this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to search for UTF-8 files with BOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom)

Comment: Somehow it's showing the validated source code as literally `Cannot detect language.<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pages literally contain the string `Cannot detect language.` before your DOCTYPE.

It seems that it’s not contained in the HTML delivered to all browsers, all the time. I just saw it with [Web (formerly Epiphany)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_%28web_browser%29), but now it’s gone.

Downloading a page with [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) might still show it to you (still does for me).