# PHP leave empty chars

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I'm a beginner in PHP and I have got a problem. PHP on my website have to get title from MySQL and print it in . PHP code is on the top of website. I've checked it in W3 Validator and there is: "Error: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected e.g. .
From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 6
 there are some chars which W3 validator shows as an error. Could You tell me what's wrong ? If php code is in  everything is ok, but how to set title or metadata with php by that way ?

```
<?php
require_once('db.php'); //class with db connection
require_once('settings.php'); //settings class

$db = new db;
$dbconn = $db->connect();

$settings = new settings;
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

<title><?php echo $settings->get('title',$db_prefix,$db);?></title>

...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML validation error: Non-space characters found before DOCTYPE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051941/html-validation-error-non-space-characters-found-before-doctype)

Answer (score -1):

for this reason you must delete all space between in php and html code

for example :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<?php
 require_once('db.php'); //class with db connection
 require_once('settings.php'); //settings class
 $db = new db;
 $dbconn = $db->connect();
 $settings = new settings;
?> 
<head> 
<title><?php echo $settings->get('title',$db_prefix,$db);?></title>
...
```

Comment: Now it's better, but Validator still shows errors: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
From line 2, column 17; to line 3, column 7
lang="pl">↩<head>